# How to build a web voice chat with rooms?

Tags: python, sockets, flask, video, webrtc

At the moment, my friends and I have created a Flask application that can log in a user and register a user. It stores their email, username, and password to a database.

Our main goal of setting up voice chat between users is very difficult to perform and we're kind of stuck and unsure of how to get to that point.

We'd ideally like to allow users to look at a list of available rooms (available meaning that there are less than 5 users). However, we don't know how to even get a video call between two users. I haven't found many libraries that work with flask. I learned about socket-io. However, that delivers a text chat function which is secondary to what we wish to achieve.

If you could please provide any help or sense of direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adapting something like https://github.com/TomPrograms/Python-Voice-Chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in postgressql you can do something like this

```
select name from roms where members < 5;
```

it will only return chat rooms with space. and for video chatting you can give this a shot
https://www.agora.io/en/blog/build-a-scalable-video-chat-app-with-agora-in-flask/
i am not a flask user but I guess it should get the job done